# Count the number of pages returned by twitter search API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, twitter

Is there a way to count the number of pages returned by the twitter search API? I'm just trying to get an idea if there's a way to access how many pages there are for a specific query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, there is no way to get "total number of pages", or total number of records, for a twitter query. If you look at twitters interface, or anything that uses twitter, they don't have any number of pages represented. What you should do instead, is to have a "load more tweets" option that goes to the next page, instead of having a "page 1 of 10".

That kind of paging is by many considered obsolete anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

The t[witter search API](http://search.twitter.com/api/) says this:

> The API also supports the following
>   optional URL parameters:
>
> ...
>   rpp: the number of tweets to
>   return per page, up to a max of 100.
>   E.g.,
>   http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=devo&rpp=15
>
> page: the page number to return, up to
>   a max of roughly 1500 results (based
>   on rpp * page) ...

so yeah, there is a way, but that depends on how many tweets per page you want to get.

Comment: yeah I saw that, but I was wondering if there is anything that is specifically returned that I can use